# CSS - ISSUE - Small thumbnail images get HUGE - and block the entire display

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

On one of my sites, while the page loads images appear much bigger than they are supposed to (as specified in the CSS)

I was thinking that it might be something related to the size of the images, but no.
I tried changing the 'display' property but that did not help either. I'm thinking that perhaps it's some JS related resizing issue, but I don't really know how to test for it. The blocks are powered by OWL-Carousel, but I tried searching for such an issue and came up empty handed.

** Thanks for the answer - which was given by Benjamin. The issue was caused by FOUC, Above the fold rendering of the elements. Once I added the "critical CSS" (that loads before OWL carousel actually does), the issue dissepated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're dealing with is something akin to what's known as FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content) - though the cause for you appears to be related to your "owl carousel" which takes a moment to initialize, and your site relies on *that* for the actual final appearance.

You don't have any CSS that gets the layout *close enough* before the Owl Carousel loads in. If you applied something like the following CSS to it, it would get it pretty close (at least on desktop, I didn't check the actual appearance before/after on mobile, but that could be amended with an `@media` query)

```
.scolumns {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scolumns > .column {
    width: 248px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Basically, if you rely on JavaScript based DOM manipulation for your final layout, you'll either want to apply some CSS that gets it close first (and doesn't affect the final layout, hence the [Direct Child Combinator above: `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) - your carousel adds containers, so it won't affect it after it's done loading") - or use some kind of loading animation on the parent element that you hide when it's fully loaded.

Comment: Hi @Xhynk, Thanks for your help. Here a year later, I'm facing the same issue. :) I was able to fix it last time with your provided CSS, but this time around it seems to use a different code. However, I can't seem to find a way in Chrome to stop the loading process at the exact time the page renders incorrectly. It would be easy from there to fix the CSS that is causing it to appear incorrectly. Is there a way to achieve this? The issue appears on: http://tozsdeforum.ethermedia.hu/

Comment: *** EDIT *** I managed to fix the issue to some degree, by reloading the browser and stopping the refresh manually and hitting the jackpot after about the 35th time. However, this method does not signal "professional" to me. :D Is there a better way to deal with this in the future?